# Xml Serialization - ignore parent node 

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following class:

```
    public class product 
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AreaImageCaption")]
        public List<AreaImageCaption> AreaImageCaptions { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("image")]
        public List<string> images { get; set; }
    }

    public class AreaImageCaption
    {
        public string area_image { get; set; }
        public string area_caption { get; set; }
    }
```

When I serialize it, it outputs the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>100</name>
            <AreaImageCaption>
                <area_image>image1</area_image>
                <area_caption>caption1</area_caption>
            </AreaImageCaption>
            <AreaImageCaption>
                <area_image>image2</area_image>
                <area_caption>caption2</area_caption>
            </AreaImageCaption>
            <image>img1.jpg</image>
            <image>img2.jpg</image>
        </product>
    </products>
```

But I need it to hide the "AreaImageCaption" node, so it would look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <name>100</name>

        <area_image>image1</area_image>
        <area_caption>caption1</area_caption>
        <area_image>image2</area_image>
        <area_caption>caption2</area_caption>

        <image>img1.jpg</image>
        <image>img2.jpg</image>
    </product>
</products>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it outputs the XML you have shown? Isn't there a `AreaImageCaption` closing and opening node between the two elements?

Comment: yes you're right. It does have an AreaImageCaption tag around the 2 elements. I've just edited the code. Any ideas on how to hide it?

Comment: @user441365, this tag is there for purpose. If you remove it you are no longer capable of distinguishing between the different elements of the list.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes you might be right but I do need to remove it, and that doesn't break the XML validation. Any ideas?

Comment: @user441365, my point is that even if that doesn't break the XML validation it breaks the semantics => you can no longer use a list as object.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, right I see what you mean. so what should I replace the list with then?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of serialization, create two more properties like your `images` one:

```
[XmlElement("area_caption")]
public List<string> area_captions 
{ 
    get
    {
        return (from item in AreaImageCaptions select item.area_caption).ToList();
    }
}
[XmlElement("area_image")]
public List<string> area_images
{ 
    get
    {
        return (from item in AreaImageCaptions select item.area_image).ToList();
    }
}
```

You will also need to mark your `AreaImageCaptions` with an `[XmlIgnore]` attrbute to avoid double entries.

Comment: Hmm, this will make the XML tags appear in another order (all the captions, then all the images).

Comment: won't this make it display all the area_captions and then all the area_images, instead of pairing them together?